# Functional recursion equations

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Lets denote n-times recursion as: 
$$
f(f(f ... f(x) ...)) =  ({^nf}(x)), ({^0}f(x))=x
$$
My question is: is there general approach to solve 'algebraic' functional equation?
$$
a_n({^nf}(x))+a_{n-1}({^{n-1}f}(x)) ... + a_0x = 0
$$
For example: 
$ {^3f}(x) - x = 0 $ has 2 known to me solutions: $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$, $f(x)=x$ and
$ {^2f}(x) - x = 0 $ has 2 simple solutions: $f(x) = 1-x$, $f(x)=x$

In some special cases solutions are easy to find, in another - not.
I will be thankful for any references to research done in this area.

ADDITION:

For example,  $({^2}f)(x)=x$ valid for all functions $y=f(x)$ that can be expressed in the form $\psi(x,y)=\psi(y,x)$, i.e. has parameters symmetry.

Comment: You know  that just  for $n>4$ and even $f(x)=x$ there is not a "general approach"... So your general problem is hopeless.

Comment: Oh... well. That is why I am here .. to ask. Reading your comment, even a case ${^n}f(x) = x$ is hopeless.

Comment: @guestDiego The case $f(x) = x$ is pretty trivial, whatever $n$, since then ${}^n f(x) = x$ for all $n$. It's pretty hopeless for $f(x) = x^k$ with $k > 1$, since then ${}^n f(x) = x^{k^n}$.

Comment: How do I solve for a function when I can't even solve for a root in a 5th degree polynomial?  $\ddot\frown$

Comment: @Daniel Fischer You are completely right. Just a lapsus originated by the wrong  assumption  $ {}^n f(x) = x^n$. However you found a way out.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some class of function there is the concept of [Carleman/Bell matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix), converting the problem of functional iteration into that of matrix-powers.
Basically that concerns functions for which you have a power-series having a nonzero radius of convergence.
The best adapted cases are such functions, where the power series has no constant term: then the Carleman-matrix is triangular and admits powers and often even fractional powers giving power series for iterations and even fractional iterations accordingly.

The field is very wide, has a lot of, sometimes complicated, requirements. Just to make the above a bit more intuitive:

---

Consider a matrix $F$ containing columnwise the coefficients of the formal powerseries of some function $f(x)$ and of its powers $f(x)^0, f(x)^1, f(x)^2, ...$
Consider then a vectorexpression $V(x) = [1,x,x^2,x^3,...]$
Then the idea for the Carleman-matrix is, to be able to evaluate
$$ \begin{array} {rll}
   V(x) \cdot M &= [1,f(x),f(x)^2, ...] & \text{ which is also }\\
   V(x) \cdot M &= V(f(x))  & \text{ and then of course }\\
   V(f(x)) \cdot M &= V(f°^2(x)) \\
   V(f°^2(x)) \cdot M &= V(f°^3(x)) \\
   \cdots & \text{ and finally }\\
   V(x) \cdot M^h &= V(f°^h(x))
\end{array}$$
Then fractional iterates are constructed - at least their formal power series- if fractional powers of $M$ can be constructed, for instance by diagonalization or matrixlogarithm/matrixexponentiation.

If this is all possible with some given function $f(x)$ then ony can approach your examples of functional equations on iterations with polynomials with the powers of ***F*** or even series on ***F***. For instance, one approach for solving the problem of tetration is to approximate the solution of $\small (I-F)^{-1} $ (which is like a geometric series with matrix $F$ as quotient, an example can be found for instance as a sidenote in an article of P. Walker on the fractional iterate of the $\exp()$. Such series are called "Neumann-series" and have of course their own strong requirements)

---

As I said above, this is far from being trivial and as well technical as principal problems must be solved, or often cannot be solved.  Also this is only ***one*** approach to that problem of function-composition and -iteration, having already a vast amount of literature - books and online available articles...

Sidenote: the diagonalization (if possible) of a Carlemanmatrix ***F*** for some function $f(x) = a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... $ reflects/implements also the concept of the [Schröder-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%27s_equation) (That concept has been introduced around 1890 by Ernst Schröder, and developed later by G. Koenigs and others) . In the 1950/60/70 E. Jabotinsky developed specifically the attempt using the Carlemanmatrix.

Comment: Thanks. At least it paves the way to solution for certain functional classes.